# Deserialise Json into nested pojo's

Tags: java, jackson

There seem to be a few similar questions but I can't quite seem to find an answer ?

I am trying to parse the json returned by a jqGrid filter property in a controller.  To get it working I'm doing it in a very clunky way although once I have it working I'm hoping to ake a next step and pass it as a RequestBody and let Spring handle some of this.  For now I'd like to get it working this way if possible ?  Seems like it should just work out of the tin so maybe I've made a foolish error ?

json sample

```
  {"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"accountName","op":"cn","data":"E"},{"field":"accountRef","op":"cn","data":"E"}]}
```

I've made 2 quick pojos to try and deserialise the data

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private class Filter {

    private String groupOp;
    private List<Rule> rules; 

    public String getGroupOp() {
        return groupOp;
    }
    public void setGroupOp(String groupOp) {
        this.groupOp = groupOp;
    }

    public List<Rule> getRules() {
        return rules;
    }
    public void setRules(List<Rule> rules) {
        this.rules = rules;
    }

}   

private class Rule {

        private String field;
        private String op; 
        private String data; 

        public String getField() {
            return field;
        }
        public void setField(String field) {
            this.field = field;
        }

        public String getOp() {
            return op;
        }
        public void setOp(String op) {
            this.field = op;
        }

        public String getData() {
            return data;
        }
        public void setData(String data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
}
```

The json string is in a String parameter called filter and there is this very basic code to deserialise it

```
byte[] jsonData = filter.getBytes();

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();         
Filter f = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, Filter.class);
```

My reading of samples is that this is very basic and badly written but should do the job.  Instead I get an error...

I have copied the complete error here which may be overboard ?  Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong ?

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct 
instance of com.app.AppController$Filter: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value (' {"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"accountName","op":"cn","data":"E"},{"field":"accountRef","op":"cn","data":"E"}]}')
 at [Source: [B@5bfd2bb5; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException(DeserializationContext.java:1456) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1012) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(ValueInstantiator.java:370) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:315) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1290) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:159) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:150) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3798) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2929) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at com.app.AppController.downloadAccounts(AppController.java:580) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.app.AppController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6a077f1a.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.0.M3.jar:5.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.M3.jar:5.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.M3.jar:5.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.M3.jar:5.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.M3.jar:5.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.M3.jar:5.0.0.M3]
    at com.app.AppControllerController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8ff0ac7a.downloaAccounts(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.M3.jar:5.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.M3.jar:5.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.M3.jar:5.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.M3.jar:5.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.M3.jar:5.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.M3.jar:5.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.M3.jar:5.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.M3.jar:5.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:964) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.M3.jar:5.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:856) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.M3.jar:5.0.0.M3]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:841) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.M3.jar:5.0.0.M3]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-5.0.0.M3.jar:5.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.0.M3.jar:5.0.0.M3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that both `Filter` and `Rule` are private inner classes. That's why Jackson cannot create instances of them. Try making them public nested classes, i.e. declare them as `public static` classes, or move them to separate source files.

I've also noticed in the stacktrace that your array of bytes contains a single quote at the beginning and another one at the ending. You should remove them, the first character should be an opening brace and the last one a closing brace. Otherwise, `readValue` takes it as if it were a string.

Comment: Right, sorry I see what you mean, I've put them into separate files now and so they are standard public classes.   I think the ' is just part of the debug to mark it as a string, if I do a System.out.println they are not there.  I still seem to be getting the same error though.  I'll sleep on it and try again in the morning!  Thanks for the help !

Comment: Thanks, apologies you were correct Spring (?) is adding quotes to the parameter and also including the escape characters as actual characters (possibly there is a inbuilt method to reconvert ?).  Any way - some fields being misaligned but I think that is a different question if I can't solve it!  Thanks very much.